# Understanding the Git Workflow

Tags: git, github, git-workflow

Please have some patience as I am still trying to find my way around with git.
The whole practice of forking and branching all over the place makes it a bit harder to grok what's going on.

I am trying to get a workflow going but, I'm running into hurdles. So far, this is what I have:

**1.** Fork project

**2.** Clone the fork locally

```
   $ git clone git@github.com:MyName/foo.git
```

**3.** Add the upstream remote so your fork can be kept up to date

```
   $ git remote add upstream git@github.com:OriginalName/foo.git
```

**4** Working on a branch in the clone:

```
   $ git checkout -t origin/branchName
```

**5** Update from the orginal (upstream) project's branch:

```
   $ git fetch upstream
   $ git merge upstream/branchName
```

**6** Commit and push changes in my fork

```
   $ git commit -a -m "some message"
   $ git push
```

How do I get the changes in my fork to the original project? I'm told pull requests but, I can't find the command to run to make that happen. Google hasn't been to helpful.

Should I checkout the branch from upstream, merge my fork, and push?

Should I clone the original project in a different directory, add the fork as an upstream, merge, and push?

Comment: Do you control both repositories? I think it's up to the owner to decide whether to merge changes.

Comment: @Blender yes. Thus the question. I'm trying to find the best way to do that :-)

Answer (score 2):

The pull request is done in the Github page of your project.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

"Pull request" is a GitHub function, not a git function.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is called the *integrator workflow*, also known as the *integration manager workflow*. Many developers find this confusing first, especially after working with centralised version control systems for a long time.

Good news: it is fairly simple, but **you need to understand what "blessed repository", "forking", "commit", "push" and "pull" mean** and how to correctly setup the access rights on the different reports used.

We at Intland made a tutorial for our team: [What is the Integrator  Workflow?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67zQHNO2gaQ) If you have 6 minutes, it is worth a watch.